# Is it able to undo ">" command?

Tags: shell, command-line, io-redirection

I just type the command `echo "text" > a.txt` which a.txt initially has contents inside.
And now all `a.txt` left is "text".
It seems like I can't undo it even with an editor.
Is it possible to save back the origin contents in a.txt?

Comment: Seems you have overwritten the file and hence lost the content

Comment: Short answer: No. Longer answer: Not without a proper, previously defined backup. Think before you type